# I set a variable and added it to a dictionary and the dictionary doesn't print it

Tags: python, variables, dictionary

I set 'a' to equal user input and I want it to be stored in the dictionary with each letter separately and numbered, this is the code:

```
a = input("Please enter your text: ")

mydict = {}
for x in range(len(a)):
  mydict[x] = a[x]

print (mydict[4])
```

but when I run it, it's supposed to show the fifth letter from the dictionary but it just show this error:

```
    print (mydict[4])
KeyError: 4

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: Yeah, because if you are not in the interpreter shell, you need to `print(mydict)` if you want to see any output.

Comment: *Aside*: A shorter version might be: `mydict = dict(enumerate(a))`

Comment: So, (since your edit changed the question), how long was your input? What happens if you just assign `a='12345'` instead, so your program is actually self-contained and reproducible?

Comment: @Useless The problem is not with the the input, rather it is with the 'print', how do I print a certain letter, this doesn't work           Print (dict[4]) what other way can I do it to print a certain letter

Comment: You claim it doesn't work, but refuse to provide code that other people can test themselves to confirm this. Your example is [neither complete nor verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). How much effort do you expect random strangers to expend helping you, when you won't do your part?